# How can I get individual page of my existing website and show them in different layouts of my android app

Tags: android, webview

```
mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.real_cake_website);
WebSettings webSettings= mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.realcake.in/");  
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

I have a website realcake.in , which I converted into android app by simply using webView (downloading the direct url) in my Activity class. I am able to show my web application into my android app. but it does not feel like an app.

Is there a better way to convert my website(or any online shopping website) into proper android app?

Can we get individual page of our website embedded to android app using layout or something? please suggest.

How can I get individual page of my existing website and show them in different layouts of my android app?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Answer to first Question:**  To convert your website into app you have to develop a proper android application.Depending on your
   requirements you can either develop a native or hybrid app.(Native
   has better UI and more fast).

   2. **Answer to Second Question:** You can definitely embed your website into a webview in a layout,but it is not always a good option.If
      your website is not mobile responsive the page may not load
      properly.
   3. **Answer to Third Question:** There are multiple options to do this.You can define different layouts for your websites.Each layout
      will contain webview and each of them will be loaded with different
      url.

   ---

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try your suggestion. My actual requirement is to use my existing website in optimized way possible to build an android app out of it and to have genuine look and feel of app.please suggest the best way to accomplish the same. you can have look of my website at :  http://www.realcake.in/

Comment: Its a good mobile responsive e-commerce based website.My suggestion is to make a good native android application for this website.As users will be buying your products using paypal or other payment gateways,and its UI should look good,so I suggest that you should go ahead  for a native android application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am working to make native app for the same.